# How to wait until promise finishes before continuing the loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, promise

I want to wait until a promise finishes before continuing in my for loop. See similar code below. As is, the loop will run many times and run all of the promises but this is not ideal for my application. I need the program to run the while loop, run the promise, wait until that resolves, check to see if 10 seconds has passed or the user variable has been set, if not, run again.

```
var p = promiseReturnedFromAFunction();
var time = new Date().getTime();
var user = 'undefined';
while(user === 'undefined' && Math.abs(time - new Date().getTime()) < 10000) {
     p.then(() => {
         if(somecondition) {
              user='user';
              break;
         }
     })
     //Code should wait here until the above promise is done before continuing
}
```

If anyone could help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you just put your code inside the callback?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? Where should I put what code?

Comment: p.then(() => { if(somecondition){ } /*put your code here*/ }) //not here }

Comment: A promise only ever resolves once. Expecting it's resolved value to change due to calling .then again without any other action occuring inbetween that changes what `p` is doesn't make sense.

Comment: var p = promiseReturnedFromAFunction() could result in different values each time it is called

Comment: You need to rethink your steps: run the while loop(sync), run the promise(async), wait until that resolves(async), check to see if 10 seconds(sync).

Comment: Most likely a while loop simply can't be used in this case without also using async/await. A synchronous loop cannot be forced to "wait" on an asynchronous callback.

Answer (score -1):

```
var p = promiseReturnedFromAFunction();
var time = new Date().getTime();
var user = 'undefined';

p.then(() => {
   while(user === 'undefined' && Math.abs(time - new Date().getTime()) < 10000) {
         if(somecondition) {
              user='user';
              break;
         }
    }
});
```

I think you have it inverted.  You want to wait for the promise to resolve, then loop through your condition checks to make sure user is set or the time has elapsed.

Comment: How would I call p again from inside that function if the user and time conditions are not met?

Comment: Why would you need to run p again?  You just need to run your loop and check the other conditions at that point.

Comment: The values from the promise can change over time. Thats why I need to check again

Comment: @AllAnimals uhm... no they can't.. Once a promise is resolved, it's resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I am not clear on what the desired behavior you're trying to achieve is. Is it to try and determine a value, retrying every X seconds if unable to? Refresh the value every X seconds?

The only immediate advice I can give is that once you have to wait on a promise, you generally need/want to keep chaining that with other promises and resolves. You don't want to try and "block" on a promise to break out of it. So you either want to resolve `p` and then do looping inside the resolve, or you should invert the logic a bit and write a loop that will check `somecondition` and only resolve `p` once that is true.